# Crear múltiples tablas usando el bucle for en python

Tags: python, bucle-for, dataframe

Tengo una tabla inicial (*df*), donde las columnas son: *Departamento, 2015, 2016, 2017*.
Deseo crear varias tablas, manteniendo la columna *Departamento* en todas ellas, pero cambiando los años en cada una, es decir:

```
df_2015 = df[['Departamento','2015']]
df_2016 = df[['Departamento','2016']]
df_2017 = df[['Departamento','2017']]
```

He intentado iterar este proceso con *for* usando el siguiente código:

```
for i in range(2015,2018):
    globals()['df_{}'.format(i)] = df[['Departamento',i]]
```

Pero obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
KeyError: '[2015] not in index'
```

Entiendo que el error esta en no incluir la comilla *'i'* en el bucle. Quisiera saber como puedo corregir este código o si existe una mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas  as pd
liston = []
data = {
    "Departamento": [ "algo", "otro" ],
    "2015": [ 100, 200 ],
    "2016": [ 111, 211 ],
    "2017": [ 122, 222 ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame( data )    

for i in range( 2015, 2018 ):

       # creamos un nuevo dataframe
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()

       # copiamos las columnas correspondientes
    df2[[ "Departamento", str( i ) ]] = df[[ "Departamento", str( i ) ]]

       # agregamos el dataframe a la lista
    liston.append( df2 )
    
for lis in liston:
    print( lis )
```

Imprime:

Departamento  2015
0         algo   100
1         otro   200
Departamento  2016
0         algo   111
1         otro   211
Departamento  2017
0         algo   122
1         otro   222

Comment: No es lo que busco Marce. Ten en cuenta que quiero generar nuevas tablas. Por ejemplo si tengo un df con 4 columnas: A,B,C,D. Lo que busco es crear 3 tablas. Que la primera tabla tenga las columnas A y B, la segunda A y C, y la tercera A y D.

Comment: @Alexander Calsina Gutierrez, Bueno, creo haber entendido tu necesidad, dime si ahora está bien.

Comment: Excelente @Marce Puente. Es lo que buscaba.